# Java Spring 5 Get and findById mongo MonoOnErrorResume

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Spring newbie here, trying to make a **GET** http query in a mongo db via **findById(id, Object**).

But it doesn't seem to be working. I can ***POST*** and ***PUT*** but when calling a query via ID i get this err **MonoOnErrorResume**

- I'm using EmbeddedMongoDB

**Controller**

```java
public class ContentController {
    public static final String CONTENT_V_1_CONT = "/contents/v1/cont/";

    private final ContentService contentService;

    @Autowired
    public ContentController(ContentService contentService) {
        this.contentService = contentService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "{id}", produces = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Mono<Content> getContent(@PathVariable String id) {
       System.out.println(contentService.getContent(id)); // 
       MonoOnErrorResume
     return contentService.getContent(id);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "", produces = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Mono<Content> createContent(@RequestBody Mono<Content> content){
       return  contentService.createContent(content);
     }
```

**Service Implmentation**

```java
public final ReactiveMongoOperations reactiveMongoOperations;

@Autowired
public ContentServiceImplementation(ReactiveMongoOperations reactiveMongoOperations) {
   this.reactiveMongoOperations = reactiveMongoOperations;
}

@Override
public Mono<Content> getContent(String id) {
   return reactiveMongoOperations.findById(id, Content.class);
}

@Override
public Mono<Content> createContent(Mono<Content> contentMono) {
   return reactiveMongoOperations.save(contentMono);
}
```

**Data Config Dont know is this is useful**

```java
@Bean
public ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoClient mongoClient){
   return new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, DATABASE_NAME);
}

@Bean
public ReactiveMongoOperations reactiveMongoTemplate(ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory){
   return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(mongoDatabaseFactory);
}
```

Lmk if i'm missing some critical info

Comment: Found my error, it was in the model, mistyped the getId getter method.

Comment: I had my id like so 
@Id private 
String content_id 

when i switched it to id it all plugged into play

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may come from your controller, you declare your path like so:

```
@GetMapping(path = "{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

So unless you have a `/` at the end of your controller class mapping you will have issues because your final URL will look like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/my/route/get1
```

instead of :

```
http://localhost:8080/my/route/get/1
```

Your `@PathVariable` looks strange as well, try doing this instead :

```
@PathVariable("id") String id
```

To ensure Spring is going to map `{id}` to your `@PathVariable`

Comment: I tried changing the path variable but still getting nothing, i'm getting a response status of 200 but the response object is still coming empty.

I also updated my code above so you can see the route path, I do have the path set up like you wrote out.